# How to scrape a table with selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, xpath

I'm having a weird issue trying to scrape a table with selenium. For reference, the table is the item table [here](https://www.dotabuff.com/heroes/ancient-apparition), although ideally I would like to be able to scrape any item table for any hero on this site.

```py
self.item_table_xpath = '//table[descendant::thead[descendant::tr[descendant::th[contains(text(), "Item")]]]]'

def retrieve_hero_stats(self, url):
        self.driver.get(url)
        try:
            win_rate_span = self.driver.find_element(by = By.XPATH, value = '//dd[descendant::*[@class = "won"]]/span')
        except:
             win_rate_span = self.driver.find_element(by = By.XPATH, value = '//dd[descendant::*[@class = "lost"]]/span')
        win_rate = win_rate_span.text
        hero_name = url.split('/')[-1]
        values = list()
        for i in range(1, 13):
            values.append({
               'Item Name': self.driver.find_element(by = By.XPATH, value = self.item_table_xpath + f'/tbody/tr[{i}]' + '/td[2]').text,
               'Matches Played': self.driver.find_element(by = By.XPATH, value = self.item_table_xpath + f'/tbody/tr[{i}]' + '/td[3]').text,
               'Matches Won': self.driver.find_element(by = By.XPATH, value = self.item_table_xpath + f'/tbody/tr[{i}]' + '/td[4]').text,
               'Win Rate': self.driver.find_element(by = By.XPATH, value = self.item_table_xpath + f'/tbody/tr[{i}]' + '/td[5]').text
            })
        print(hero_name)
        print(values)
```

The issue is the output of the code is inconsistent; sometimes the fields in the values list are populated, and sometimes they are not. This changes each time I run my code. I don't necessarily need someone to write this code for me, in fact, I'd prefer you didn't, I'm just stumped as to why the output changes every time I run?

Comment: So you are trying to scrape the data from here: https://www.dotabuff.com/heroes/ancient-apparition/items ? I'm confused. If not that page, post a screenshot with the table you're after.

Comment: maybe page needs time to put elements and you have to sleep() few seconds